# Removing Punctuations in a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm working on removing punctuations that can exist either beginning or end of a string or could be both. 
ex. "!!Hello**"
I want an output of: "Hello" with all of the punctuations removed.

```
char s[] = "!!Hello**";
ch [] = NULL;
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ( isalpha(s[i]) ) {
        ch[i]=s[i];
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    ch[i] = '\0';
}
```

The block of code does not seem to copy the strings to ch. No idea why!!

Comment: do you know how to program in C? if not, I would start there (i.e. a good book - does the above code compile? or did you paste some bits together)?

Comment: Do you need to keep the original string, or can you modify that?

Comment: I assume isalpha() checks for alphanumeric characters but would be nice to see it since your problem might be there. Also how is length computed? Finally the indentation is horrible >.< plz fix it

Comment: ch needs to be allocated to have some size

Comment: I need to modify the string, remove all the punctuations and just leave off the letters.

Answer (score 4):

You could change it inplace:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char s[] = "!!Hello**";
  size_t pos = 0;
  for (char *p = s; *p; ++p)
    if (isalpha(*p))
      s[pos++] = *p;
  s[pos] = '\0';
  printf("'%s'\n", s);
}
```

#### Output

```
'Hello'
```

Or using only pointers:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void filter_alpha(char *s) {
  for (char *p = s; *p; ++p)
    if (isalpha(*p))
      *s++ = *p;
  *s = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "!!Hello**";
  filter_alpha(s);
  printf("'%s'\n", s);
}
```

#### To remove only leading/trailing non-alpha characters

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // isalpha()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strlen()

char* strip_nonalpha_inplace(char *s) {
  for ( ; *s && !isalpha(*s); ++s)
    ; // skip leading non-alpha chars
  if (*s == '\0')
    return s; // there are no alpha characters

  assert(isalpha(*s));
  char *tail = s + strlen(s);
  for ( ; !isalpha(*tail); --tail)
    ; // skip trailing non-alpha chars
  assert(isalpha(*tail));
  *++tail = '\0'; // truncate after the last alpha

  return s;
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "!!Hello**";
  printf("'%s'\n", strip_nonalpha_inplace(s));
}
```

Comment: did you mean "int" for size_t ?

Comment: This will remove any non alpha character inside the string too, the OP wanted leading and trailing removed only.

Comment: @IanNorton: I understand that the OP wants to remove all punctuations, but in his input it may exists only at the start/end. This solution also works for such input.

Comment: @IanNorton: I've added variant that removes only leading/trailing non-alpha characters.

Answer (score 1):

You sort of have the right idea, but you've missed some of the essential things when dealing with strings in C (like strlen)

This *should* remove any leading and trailing non-alphanumeric ASCII characters.

```
#include <string.h>

char * remove_outer_punctuation( char * text )
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    char * start = text;

    if ( text == NULL ) return NULL;

    len = strlen(text);

    if ( len < 1 ) return start;

    // advance start to the first alphanum character
    for ( i = 0 ; i < len; i++ ){
       if ( !isalpha(text[i]) ) { 
           start++;
       } else {
           continue;
       }
    }

    // find the final alphanumeric character and 
    // put a NUL after it
    for ( i = len; i > 0; i-- ){
       if ( isalpha(text[i] ) continue;
    }
    text[i+1] = 0x0;

    return start;
}
```

Be warned though, this will modify the input string ( we insert NUL ). If you don't want it do do that, use strcpy first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues:

```
ch [] = NULL;
```

this should have a type in it's definition:

```
char ch[15];
```

Don't define `char` arrays of undefined size.

Also, what is `length` in your code?  You could use `strlen(s)` instead of `length` for which I see no definition.

For tokenization, you can use `strtok`.

To copy the strings from one array to another, use `strcpy_s`.

Comment: yup i forgot to indicate how i got length
i basically used : lenght = strlen(s);

Answer (score 0):

To remove initial stuff:

```
char * rm_head(char *str) {
  while(!isalpha(*str)) str++;
  return str;
}
```

and use it like:

```
  char *rest = rm_head(original);
```